# Let StackPanel's item to float down when there's no enought space

Tags: wpf

I've got a simple WPF application that has defined as

```
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label Content="Date" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
       <DatePickerTextBox ></DatePickerTextBox>
        <DatePickerTextBox ></DatePickerTextBox>
        <DatePickerTextBox ></DatePickerTextBox>

        <Button Margin="15,0,0,0" Content="Click me"  Height="25"  />
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="1"></Grid>
    </Grid>
```

(Please don't consider the sense of it, it's a mockup to reproduce the issue I'm facing in real app)

It shows as

[image]

When I resize it shows as

[image]

I wish that the stackpanel' s item float down in order to continue to see all of them, is this possible? how?

Comment: use wrappanel instead of stackpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rise said in the comments the correct panel to use in this case is a wrappanel not a stackpanel. A good overview of the different panel types can be found [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/)